# Can one develop for iOS 6 using XCode 5 on Mavericks (OS X 10.9)?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, xcode

## This question is out-dated. Mavericks is released and everything works fine with Xcode 5 and iOS 6 on an iPod 4th gen.

---

I'm thinking about upgrading my OS X to Mavericks, but I still want to keep developing my iOS app. I read on the internet that Xcode 4.6.3 is not compatible with Mavericks (OS X 10.9). So, this would force me to use the new Xcode 5. However, Xcode 5 comes along with the new iOS 7 SDK. The problem is that I own an iPod 4th gen, which isn't compatible with iOS 7.

So, has anyone tried this already? I think this should be possible, because at the WWDC 2013, Apple was so proud to tell that more than 90% of the costumers work with the latest iOS, which is currently still iOS 6. But with the release of iOS 7, they will be ruining that fact, because iOS 7 doesn't seem to be compatible with iPod 4th Gen. And a lot of people own such a device.

Did I miss something, or is Apple going to wrong way?

Comment: In the past, it's been possible to develop for n-2 versions when a new one comes out. Until Xcode 5 and Mavericks hit general release, your best bet might be https://developer.apple.com/devforums/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yep.

I deploy onto my 4th gen touch from Xcode 5 on ML - not Mavericks, but should be the same.

Note, though, that you won't be able to submit to the App Store from Xcode 5 until just before iOS 7 is released.

Note, though, that you want to install Mavericks onto a **seperate partition**!!! Don't make it the only OS on your machine until it is released.

Comment: Yeah, I did a test install of Mavericks on a separate partition and it also works there. Do you know a way to develop on Mavericks and submit to the App Store?

Comment: @Mart Not if what you read on the Interwebs is true - but I would guess that Xcode 4.x should run on Mavericks. Try it!

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a try soon. I'm now booted in Mountain Lion :)

Comment: too bad, i installed mavericks. I am able to submit ios app from Xcode 4.x while unable to submit mac apps

Answer (score 11):

You can install Xcode 4 by temporary editing the System Version.

1. go to /system/library/coreservices
2. Find SystemVersion.plist and open it
3. Change the two bottom numbers (10.9) to 10.8.4 and save
4. Install Xcode 4
5. Change those numbers back to 10.9 and save.

Done, You now have Xcode 4 on 10.9 :)

Good Luck!

Comment: Just download Xcode 4 and install from developer.apple.com. No need to change system versions.

Comment: @Sam Guichelaar That does not work, as it will say "Xcode Install Assistant cannot be installed on this disk. The version of OS X is too new"

Answer (score 1):

I was also running the same problem when I updated to xcode 5 it removed older sdk. But I taken the copy of older SDK from another computer and the same you can download from following link.

http://www.4shared.com/zip/NlPgsxz6/iPhoneOS61sdk.html
(www.4shared.com test account test@yopmail.com/test)

There are 2 ways to work with.

1) Unzip and paste this folder to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs & restart the xcode.

But this might again removed by Xcode if you update xcode.

2) Another way is Unzip and paste where you want and go to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs and create a symbolic link here, so that the SDK will remain same even if you update the Xcode.

Another change I made, Build Setting > Architectures > standard (not 64) so list all the versions of Deployment Target

**No need to download the zip if you only wanted to change the deployment target.**

Here are some screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install Xcode4 and Xcode5 on the same Maverick system. Just download Xcode 4 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and drag Xcode.app to Desktop, rename it to Xcode4.app and move it to /Applications.

Done!

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I'm going to edit this question. It is not relevant anymore. This question was relevant when Mavericks was only in a developer preview.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, change the Deployment Target and set it to 6.1, even im also working on OS X 10.9 but want to use simulator 6.1.3 with Xcode 5. Im little confused that OS X 10.9 is going to support Simulator 6.1.3 with Xcode 5 or not. I want to make Simulator 7.0 look like iphone frame when it runs but nothing happening ...