# Xcode 5 does not see devices with ios 6.1.3

Tags: ios6, xcode5

I see my device in organizer with a green dot. But I can't run my project, because there is no  iOS 6 device in destination menu.

With ios7 everything is ok.

Comment: You need to manually copy SDK 6.1 from Xcode 4.6 to Xcode 5.

Comment: This one may be help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197873/can-one-develop-for-ios-6-using-xcode-5-on-mavericks-os-x-10-9

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my fault. I set minimum iOS version to iOS 7, and forgot about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the iOS 6 SDK on XCode 5.

For that you need to have XCode 4 and XCode 5 on your Mac.

1/ In terminal :

cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

2/ Create a symbolic link in this folder to the older SDK
for example for me :

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode4/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk ./iPhoneOS6.1.sdk

3/ Go to the Project settings and chose your SDK

[image]

4/ Do only that for iPhoneOS. The support for the simulator need to be done from the XCode Preference menu

[image]

++