# Xcode 5 deployment target limited only to iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

What should be done for me to have the deployment target lower that 7.0 in my project preferences? Now any new project I create using Xcode 5 can only be deployed to iOS 7.0. That's how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can directly type a different target (5.0, 5.1, etc) into the text box :)

The only thing to note is you will need to change the architecture to exclude ARM64 if you go below 7.0.

Comment: Great. That's what I didn't notice - ARM64. New thing that nobody needs yet. Thanks!

Comment: It took me a while to realize that you cannot type it in the **Build Settings** pane, but you can do it in the **Info** pane

Comment: TY Jack, in XCode 6.1 I changed architecture to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT) and it let me choose lower iOS  down to 4.3 in Targets>General>Deployment Infro>Deployment Tagret

Answer (score 22):

Had the same issue. All I did was to change Architectures to Standard architectures (armv7,armv7s) - exclude the 64 bit. See screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it with these steps:

1. project > Build Setting
2. Deployment tab >  iOS Deployment Target

so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912484/xcode-5-does-not-see-devices-with-ios-6-1-3/18912834#18912834) to use the iOS 6 SDK on XCode 5 but you need to have XCode 4 installed on your Mac.

But I think you can just set the Deployment Target to iOS6, in the configuration of the project :

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know that. Already have the 6.1 SDK in Xcode 5 imported from the previous Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Project
2. Targets > Build Setting >Deployment Tab
3. Change ios Deployment target [See In Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVGM2.jpg)