# I can't change my deployment target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I had upgrade my  Xcode 4.6 to 5. so after that i  started working on new application which  the deployment target is 7.0. I want to run this application in 6.1 also. But there is no option available in deployment target.

What can I do?

Comment: you want to run in simulator iOS6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Valid Architecture in Build Settings. And then set the deployment target what you want.
[image]

Comment: Because 64 bit architecture support was introduced in iOS7 only. So if you want to support iOS 6 you need to change this to armv7 and armv7s.

Answer (score 0):

go in Build Setting and search `iOS Deployment Target`

Here you can change the target of the app

Comment: I did it but it still produced in the 17.0 version such as Runner_iphoneos17.0-arm64

Answer (score 0):

You can type 6.1 into the Deployment Target text box.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010149/xcode-5-deployment-target-limited-only-to-ios-7), the dudes offered some good solutions.