# Minimum target iOS version/device platform for iPhone-App to get uploaded at AppStore

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, version

what is the allowed minimum target iOS version and device platform for a new iPhone App to get uploaded on AppStore

Comment: iOS 4.3 minimum deployment target

Answer (score 7):

Apple support **iOS 4.3** [see Setting Deployment Info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html). But support **64-Bit Binary** [minimum deployment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) target of iOS 5.1.1

[Apple has officially announced apps need to be compiled with **Xcode5** starting February 1, 2014:](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a)

[image]

So you must have **Xcode5** for submission app in to app store. And in to **xCode5** we can not define device platform like`(iPhone4,iPhone4s,iPhone5,iPhone5s.. etc.)` we can set deployment Target so you can setting minimum deployment `target is 6.0` if you want to less then `6.0` and if you are not find that Option like Bellow image you can directly type in to Deployment Target filed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Building with Xcode 5 is currently required for iOS App Store submission.  Xcode 5 does not include an armv6 compiler, thus does not support building for the original iPhone (2G) or the iPhone 3G, which only run armv6 code, or for iOS versions below 4.3, which also require armv6 code.  So the 3GS and iOS 4.3 and newer are the supported lower limits.

Note that using Xcode 5 to build arm64 binaries for the newest devices has a Deployment Target lower limit of iOS 5.1.1.  Anything lower won't create a functional build.

However, there are reports that one can additionally build the app with old Xcode 4.3 or earlier, which does include an armv6 compiler, and then use lipo to combine the results with an Xcode 5 build archive to support both newer and older devices down to iOS 4.0.  Manual plist editing before codesigning may also be required after using lipo.  Apple might currently be approving a small number of such lipo builds, however it is unknown whether they will continue to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from June 1st, 2015, [APP updates needs to be 64bit and built with ios8 SDK](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer:

I think Minimum target iOS version which apple should support be 4.3.

Check this if you want to add more targets: [XCode 5 deployment target limited only to iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010149/xcode-5-deployment-target-limited-only-to-ios-7)