# when i build app in xcode 5.1.1 given me 255 error code, where is the issues?

Tags: ios, xcode5.1

i making application on xcode 5.1.1 and min ios sdk version is 5.0 when i build applcation given me 255 error code

show below error when i build

> CompileXIB GPSLocate/StoreViewController.xib
>       cd "/Users/optimatrix/Desktop/nitin apps/x-code 5.1.1/GPSLocate"
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode
>   5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH="/Applications/Xcode 5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/.."
>       /Applications/Xcode\ 5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 5.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/optimatrix/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Smartstreet-bssuagmbjqqngobkndyfxxngxxkc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/GPSLocate/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Smartstreet.app/StoreViewController.nib
>   /Users/optimatrix/Desktop/nitin\ apps/x-code\
>   5.1.1/GPSLocate/GPSLocate/StoreViewController.xib
>
> 2014-05-08 17:21:05.677 ibtoold[9180:707] [MT] DVTAssertions:
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-5038/InterfaceBuilder/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:671
>   Details:  Failed to compile nib consisting of IBProxyObject,
>   IBProxyObject, IBUIButton, IBUIImageView, IBUIImageView,
>   IBUIImageView, IBUILabel, IBUITableView, and IBUIView.
>
> Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS
>   Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this
>   issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface
>   Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash
>   report.
>
> Exception name: IBCocoaTouchToolFailureException Exception reason:
>   Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool backtrace: Thread 12 Crashed::
>   Dispatch queue: com.apple.backboardservices.processassertion 0
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x020ea0b2 objc_msgSend + 14 1
>   BackBoardServices                 0x02c6cebb __47-[BKSProcessAssertion
>   queue_registerWithServer]_block_invoke + 197 2   libxpc.dylib
>     0x05f06778 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 65 3   libxpc.dylib
>     0x05f06235 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1687 4   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d3d5b0 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 37 5   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d30f10 _dispatch_mach_cancel_invoke + 61 6   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d30231 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 565 7   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d2afd7 _dispatch_queue_drain + 340 8   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d2ae42 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128 9   libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d2bde2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 78 10  libdispatch.dylib
>     0x05d2c127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39 11  libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x97a42e72 _pthread_wqthread + 441 12  libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x97a2adaa start_wqthread + 30
>
> Backtrace of last command:   0  0x000000010c359dad (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   1  0x000000010c308ae6 (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   2  0x000000010c3087c2 (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   3  0x000000010c308dfb (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   4  0x000000010c309116 (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   5  0x0000000104d6f7b1
>   __47-[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   6  0x0000000104d940c9 -[IBDocument
>   assertIfArbitrationIsScheduledDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   7
>   0x0000000104d6f722 -[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   8  0x0000000104b49f8b (in ibtoold)   9 
>   0x0000000104b4d3ad (in ibtoold)  10  0x0000000104b57b65 (in ibtoold) 
>   11  0x0000000104b580c0 (in ibtoold)  12  0x0000000104b57f90 (in
>   ibtoold)  13  0x0000000104b563e7 (in ibtoold)  14  0x0000000104b577b7
>   (in ibtoold)  15  0x0000000104b56d6e (in ibtoold)  16 
>   0x00007fff8bffa7e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)  17  0x0000000000000001
>
> Exception backtrace: (null) Exception info:{
>       IBUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed.
>   (IBMessageChannelErrorDomain error 1.)\""; }
>
> Function: void IBAssertMarshallingFailure(NSString *__strong, NSString
>   *__strong) Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1} Hints: None Backtrace:   0  0x0000000105d1ee09
>   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in DVTFoundation)   1  0x0000000105d1e59f _DVTAssertionHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   2  0x0000000105d1e7ff _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   3  0x000000010c224ae0 IBAssertMarshallingFailure (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   4  0x000000010c30896d (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   5  0x000000010c308dfb (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   6  0x000000010c309116 (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)   7  0x0000000104d6f7b1
>   __47-[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   8  0x0000000104d940c9 -[IBDocument
>   assertIfArbitrationIsScheduledDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)   9
>   0x0000000104d6f722 -[IBDocument compiledPackageWithOptions:error:] (in
>   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)  10  0x0000000104b49f8b (in ibtoold)  11 
>   0x0000000104b4d3ad (in ibtoold)  12  0x0000000104b57b65 (in ibtoold) 
>   13  0x0000000104b580c0 (in ibtoold)  14  0x0000000104b57f90 (in
>   ibtoold)  15  0x0000000104b563e7 (in ibtoold)  16  0x0000000104b577b7
>   (in ibtoold)  17  0x0000000104b56d6e (in ibtoold)  18 
>   0x00007fff8bffa7e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)  19  0x0000000000000001
>   Command /Applications/Xcode
>   5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

min sdk is 5.1 in xcode 5.1.1?

what is the issues in my application?

Comment: what is your deployment target ?

Comment: deployment target 5.0

Comment: ok and your build architecture... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010149/xcode-5-deployment-target-limited-only-to-ios-7.. this link may help you

Comment: i have remove arm64 in valid Architectures

Comment: my architechures is **standard architectures(armv7,armv7s,arm64)** ,need change it?

Comment: yes please change it.. then check will it work or not ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52302/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-nitin-kachhadiya)

Comment: what is put instead of standard architectures(armv7,armv7s,arm64)?

Comment: i change into  $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and it's work

Comment: Why, why there're even architecture options discussed ? There's a clear message: "Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator." Try to restart the simulator, sometimes it bugs out. Check your nibs ,make sure they are not corrupted.

Comment: i tried before change architechure but no luck...

Comment: when you set standard architecture to 32 bit then it will work for ios 5.0 and more, 64 bit only used in iPhone 5S, so its better to set 32 bit