# iOS app submission without a specific device

Tags: ios, iphone

Lets say I publish an iPhone application for iOS 6. Is it possible to submit an iPad version of the app without owning an iPad of a iPhone without iOS 7?

Comment: yes it is possible, but not wise.

Comment: @matt Does this trick still work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010149/xcode-5-deployment-target-limited-only-to-ios-7

Comment: @Yerpasaur Please don't miss my answer even though it's late to the party.

Comment: the fact is **you can** submit to the app store, if you don't own the device, but the fact is **it's pretty much impossible** to be a developer and submit to the app store, unless you have a recent iphone (if you're doing iphone apps) and/or ipad (if you're doing ipad apps).  it's really all-but-impossible.  start saving!  :-O

Comment: You don't have to save quite as much as you might think necessarily.  You can get used iPod touches relatively cheaply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is confusing. But, these points will make it clear -

1. You do not need to necessarily *own* any specific iOS device before submitting an
   app to the App Store. The iOS Simulators can help you in checking/testing
   your app.
2. Starting February 1, 2014 new apps and app updates submitted to the App
   Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be
   optimized for iOS 7. Be very sure while setting your Deployment Target before submitting it to the App Store. Valid for both iPhone and iPad devices.

Answer (score 4):

The posted answers are missing an important piece of information that I feel needs to be added.

While it is true you don't need any *specific* device in order to submit to the app store, assuming you're developing your project with Xcode, it is **NOT** true that you can get an app on the app store without access to at least one device that can run your app.

The very last step before submitting an app to the app store is creating the `.ipa` file, and the step before this requires the app be archived.  This must be done on a physical device that can run the app.

This means if you don't have access to a device with iOS7 on it, you can't submit an iOS7 only app.  However, if you've got a device with iOS6.1, you can submit an app that supports iOS 6.1+, including iOS7.

But another important thing to note here...

If you have an iPad only app (as you seem to suggest that's what you're developing), you can't create the `.ipa` file if you don't have an iPad to archive the project on.

If you only have an iPhone/iPod, you can create an app that supports both iPhone/iPod AND iPad and archive it on the iPhone and submit it to the app store and it will work just fine on all devices, but you cannot create an iPad only app if you do not have access to an iPad to archive the project on.