# Testing iOS 5 apps without an iOS 5 device

Tags: ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

This is a pretty lame question, but still I want to make sure before I shell out cash for an iOS 5 device.

Is there any way to test an app on iOS 5 on a device running iOS 6 or later?

I have an iPad Retina running iOS 6. I am developing an app which will support iPad 1 as well. (iOS 5). I want to test it on a device as well (instead of just relying in the iOS 5 simulator).

Any alternative to borrowing/buying someone's iPad 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can test an iOS 5 App on an iOS 6 device. But, the reverse is false.
I think is not in your interest to buy an iPad 1.

Actually, there is less than 5% user on iOS 5. So, you can set aside this version of iOS.

Have a look [here](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7/from_date:-3,to_date:0).

And, if you use XCode 5 and you want to keep iOS SDK 6, you can follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912484/xcode-5-does-not-see-devices-with-ios-6-1-3).