# Testing an app developed with SDK6 on iOS7 device

Tags: iphone, ios6, sdk, ios7

I have an app I want to update of other reasons than change of of iOS, and the work to redesign it for iOS7 is rather big and also not looking good with iOS7.
If I build it with SDK6 using Xcode 4, how do I test it on a device running iOS7. Or do I have to see how it behaves when it is coming up at App Store.
I have also Xcode 5 but with this I can not build it with SDK6, can I?
I can see the result in the iOS6 simulator after a SDK7 build but since the app does not look good with that I do not want to update it that way.
The look is ok on a iOS7 device I know, but how to test it ??
And my devices running iOS7 are not compatible with Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for you is to install Xcode 5 keeping Xcode 4 on your Mac.
For that, copy past your current Xcode 4 in a folder named `Xcode4` on your application folder and renamed Xcode.app to Xcode4.app.
After that, update your Xcode to Xcode 5 and create a symbolic link to have the iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912484/xcode-5-does-not-see-devices-with-ios-6-1-3), where I explain how to make this symbolic link.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I also found another way to do it. Just let the simulator iOS7 in Xcode5 be open when I run the app from Xcode4. It opens in iOS7. But to run it on a iOS7 device that way I have not found out.