# Updated XCode and now can't build app onto iPad device

Tags: ios, ipad

My XCode updated and I have an app that I am running on an iOS 6 iPad device and the app is built for 5.1

Now that my XCode has updated today, when I run the app in XCode to install it onto my iPad, it says

```
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination
```

So I HAVE to update my iPad in order to develop apps now? This is awful...my app worked great and was functioning fine and I don't want to update my iPad to iOS 7 and deal with all the deprecated functions and what not...

Is there a way around this?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912484/xcode-5-does-not-see-devices-with-ios-6-1-3

Answer (score 0):

Check in Xcode Organizer if that device is used for development or has lost this role on xcode actualization.