# My iPhone 3Gs isn't selectable as a target from Xcode5. Is this fixable?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-3gs

I've been trying to get my iPhone 3Gs targeted so I can test applications on it for two days now, and I am ashamed to admit I haven't achieved this goal yet. I've found the following sites and stackoverflow answers (below), but haven't been able to target my 3Gs. During this time I am able to target my iPhone 5 with ease and put applications on that phone. I do have the iOS team provisioning profile for both devices, and on my organizer window they both show with green dots next to them.

Visually, what I mean is the following:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/lt3gXLn.png]

My iPhone5 is selectable, but my 3Gs doesn't even show up.

So far what I've found is the following answers and sites:

1) http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/ -- 
Discusses how to target armv6 which is what the 3Gs is. I executed this, but under the target selection was unable to see my 3Gs as selectable. You can see in the photo that I switched the Valid Architectures to include armv6, and chose Architectures to just be armv7 and armv7s.

2) [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5) -- I have downloaded the 6.1 simulator in the preferences download section, and I have downloaded the 6.1 SDK and put that in the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs folder. Which you can see selected in the photo.

3) [Xcode 5 does not see devices with ios 6.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912484/xcode-5-does-not-see-devices-with-ios-6-1-3) -- This has the same problem I'm having, but even with those actions I cannot select my 3Gs, which the actions are the same as #2.

With digging through all of these sites and questions I did find some information that apparently on Feb 1st. 2014 there was a switch in the app store where they are no longer accepting applications designed for iOS 6.1. Does this mean that I am no longer allowed to use my 3Gs to test? Or even allowed to develop for the 3Gs any more?

Help please?

Comment: The chart at http://gigaom.com/2013/04/22/older-model-iphones-are-more-popular-than-ever/ suggests you don't really care about supporting the 3G anymore. I know, since you have one you feel differently, but it would seem you're in a very small minority if that data is valid.

Comment: I'm not so interested in supporting the old iOS's since I don't think you can even release applications for them through the App store any more. I am specifically interested in whether I can still use my 3Gs as a target for developing on a 3.5" screen. BUT, I can still go on my 3Gs which has iOS 6.1.3 and download Cut the Rope 2, so it appears that it's software that's still be supported for major developers. If that's not the case I'd love to know.

Comment: What is your Xcode version?

Comment: Have you set the minimum iOS version to less than iOS 7?  There are two version settings in build settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved a solution. I was playing around with it some more and quit and restarted Xcode 5.0.2 without any iOS device attached to my computer. When I selected the target selection button I noticed that there were two iOS devices listed there as seen in the following picture. This suggested to me that it actually was recognizing my 3Gs, just not when I had it connect. My guess is it wasn't recognized because Xcode read that it was running iOS 6.1.3. With Putz1103's suggest that there are two version settings I started digging. Putz1103 was partially correct, and I think you for the inspiration.

[image: Soultion]

Under the "General" tab, three tabs to the left of the "Build Settings" tab when the project is selected in the project navigator there are options that need to be set correctly. Under this tab in the Deployment Info section the Deployment Target needs to be selected to the correct iOS target. After selecting that my 3Gs was selectable as the target, and I was able to build my app on my 3Gs for testing.

Combined with all of my activities outlined in the original question, it is still possible to select a 3Gs as a target for development in Xcode 5.0.2 after Feb 1st 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Deployment Target of your App (not the project) to older or equal to the OS version of the phone will solve that.