# How to install Xcode 5?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

OK, as it turns out, I did not explain my question very well at all. here is a complete re-write.

I have Xcode 4/iOS SDK 6.1 installed. I want to install and use Xcode 5 but want to use iOS6.1 SDK. I know that I can download iOS6.1 SDK from Xcode 5. But, I want to avoid that since the iOS 6.1 is already in my hard drive. Is there any way I can avoid having to download iOS6.1 SDK again.

Comment: you can always download older Xcode versions from Apple and install it separately: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need. Xcode 5 supports iOS 6 integration. For more info about this, look at this post: [Can one develop for iOS 6 using XCode 5 on Mavericks (OS X 10.9)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197873/can-one-develop-for-ios-6-using-xcode-5-on-mavericks-os-x-10-9)

**EDIT**
Here is how iOS 6 SDK can be installed in Xcode 5 (requires Xcode 4 to get the SDK)

1. In finder, go to Applications, and find Xcode (4)
2. Right Click into Show package Contents
3. Navigate to Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
4. Copy iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
5. Once you download/update-to Xcode 5, go into the same folder, where you should see iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
6. Paste the SDK in this folder

Fore more information on setting up Xcode 5 for iOS 6, look here: [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

Comment: The answer above is correct as well. However, I find it easier to deal with one version rather than 2.

Comment: You can definitely deploy to iOS 6 with Xcode 5. IF you want more information on how to use the iOS 6.1 SDK, look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5

Comment: This answers my question. I tried it out and it works. A cleaner solution will be, of course, to download iOS 6.1 SDK and simulator from Xcode 5. This approach simply saves a few minutes by not having to download the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You download Xcode 5 from the Appstore.

In preferences / Download you can download the iOS 6.0 and 6.1 Simulator

In Project Info you set the iOS Development Target to 6.1 and in the Storyboard you can chose as which iOS (6.1 or 7.0) the `Views` should be displayed.

**EDIT:** Also, Xcode5 supports earlier iOS with the same files you already have. There is no need to separate iOS 7 from the earlier Versions.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot there is a simpler way to download the SDK. Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question isn't really meant for SO (More for [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)),

[Can I have multiple Xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)
[how to install two versions of xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413301/how-to-install-two-versions-of-xcode)

This should answer your question. (The installer gives you the option of where to install it; you can simply choose a different directory)

Comment: I want a single version of Xcode with both iOS 6.1 and iOS7 SDK. I do not want to edit my project in two different Xcode versions.